# How to query a date interval in a database in java?

Tags: java, database, date

I have a table and a date column where i keep timestamp value with the following format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Then i want to make a query that returns me specific time intervals. I give a start date and an end date. HEre is what i did:

```
PreparedStatement find = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("select * from transactions where transid=? and date >= ? and date <= ?");

    find.setString(1, selected.getIban());
    find.setDate(2, (Date) dt1);
    find.setDate(3, (Date) dt2);

    ResultSet res=find.executeQuery();

    while(res.next()){
        ....
    }
```

While debugging i see that dt1 and dt2 are set correctly with the following format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

This resultset has no results in it (not null, but empty) and while loop does not execute. Can't i use >= and <= to do this as i did in my query? Or is it because i store timestamp in db but query with date, and these to have different formats.

Thank you

Comment: First run your query against the database and see if it actually fetches some result.

Comment: try to use sql.Date object instant of util.Date

Comment: `dt1` must be less than or equals `dt2`, is that the case in your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. The problem was that since Date and TIMESTAMP are different kinds of variables, comparing them returns empty. To fix the problem, i just changed the query slightly:

```
PreparedStatement find = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("select * from transactions where transid=? and DATE(date) >= ? and DATE(date) <= ?");        
find.setString(1, selected.getIban());
find.setDate(2,  dt1);
find.setDate(3, dt2);
```

Now that works

Answer (score 0):

Use **preparedStatement.setTimestamp();** instead of setDate()

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimestamp

```
PreparedStatement find = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("select * from transactions where transid=? and date >= ? and date <= ?");

    find.setString(1, selected.getIban());
find.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(((Date) dt1).getTime()));
find.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(((Date) dt2).getTime()));

    ResultSet res=find.executeQuery();

    while(res.next()){
        ....
    }
```

or convert date into sting and pass

```
    PreparedStatement find = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("select * from                transactions where transid=? and date >= ? and date <= ?");

        find.setString(1, selected.getIban());
   find.setString(2, (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format((Date) dt2)));
    find.setString(3, (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format((Date) dt2)));

        ResultSet res=find.executeQuery();

        while(res.next()){
            ....
        }
```

Comment: thanks, but simpledateformat returns a string and we are trying to do setDate(2, string), which is not applicable, gives syntax error

Comment: we are not setting date we are passing date as sting ,LOOK AT ->>>>>> find.setString(2, (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format((Date) dt2)));
    find.setString(3, (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format((Date) dt2)));

Answer (score 0):

why not just try using static timestamp like

```
select * from transactions    
where data > '2013-07-16 00:00:00'
and data < '2013-07-20 00:00:00'
```

and see if the problem is in sql or in the program